# Bluetooth sound interruptions during RDP session

Tags: windows-10, audio, remote-desktop, bluetooth, system-sounds

I frequently connect from one laptop to another via RDP and experience problems with sound output. I play music via Bluetooth speaker and every time I do any thing on client/server that possibly causes system sounds, the main (music) audio stream to Bluetooth is interrupted, the song in browser shows playing and no sound is heard at all, only refresh page solves the problem. The interruption sounds include not only system sounds but apps sounds as well (Skype, MS Teams, Zoom, etc.)

The problem exists on both configurations:

1. Music is played on RDP client PC while connected to RDP server
2. Music is played on RDP-server with enabled `Play on remote computer` / `audiomode:i:1`

Things I've tried and none of them helped

1. Mute the sound on host/client
2. Enable Focus Assists, i.e. disable all notifications

Disabling one and every sound in the system including all the 3rd party apps seems inefficient for me and overkill.

Is there any way to achieve smooth sound experience without disabling sounds?

Both systems are Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you play the sound using a local speaker without using Bluetooth?

Comment: Yes, i tried  playing through local speakers and there is no interruptions, but I am particularly interested in Bluetooth experience.

Comment: And the most weird thing that interruptions even not always happen with Bluetooth, I don't know where to dig into further, what could be the reason

Comment: And let me guess your computer is connected via Wifi to the Internet? If that is the case I would assume a problem between Wifi and Bluetooth. Both are using the same frequencies and therefore can cause problems when used at the same time if the hardware was not carefully designed to avoid such problems. I would try an external USB stick for Bluetooth or Wifi on a cable placed a meter away from your PC.

Comment: what means `Wifi on a cable`? you mean try Ethernet?

Comment: No. I meant an USB Wifi stick on an usb extension cable so that the Wifi stick can be placed away from the computer.

Comment: Well, I don't have WiFi cable nor extension cable just now. You think wave interference is the cause of the issue, but I suppose sound settings is the reason. If the case is in interference then I'd observe interruptions all the time, but I definitely found out that the **trigger** is the system sounds. If nothing happens in system, then all goes fine

Comment: When music is played on the RDP client, does disabling "Play on remote computer" or `audiomode` in RDP help with the problem?

Comment: yes, it looks like it helps. The thing that drives me crazy that it is NOT CONSISTENT with enabled option! When I was trying now it suddenly stopped interrupting on RDP server. Thing trigger that causes the interruption on RDP client is that [splash screen of Teams](https://imgur.com/a/FgNi4RJ) started on RDP server. I does not remember (and don't hear) any sounds during this splash screen. WTF???

Comment: shouldn't it happen? the speakers and RDP sound are [technically two different streams](https://imgur.com/a/PM49O7j) on the system mixer that should be ran independently

Comment: They are two different streams, but both mix into the device stream. The mixer allows to mute/unmute or increase/decrease one stream from the total mix, for apps and devices. What do you mean by "Bluetooth is interrupted"? Is there a disconnection or is it muted? What do you see happening in the Volume mixer when this occurs?

Comment: `What do you mean by "Bluetooth is interrupted"? Is there a disconnection or is it muted? What do you see happening in the Volume mixer when this occurs?` no visible marks in mixer, by interrupted I mean *muted*, it is still connected in dashboard. I see playing is going on in browser but no sound comes from the speaker.

Comment: I guess I found the root cause, the BT-speaker was connected to two laptops simultaneously and this speaker doesn't allow simultaneous play of music from two sources. It still shows connected on both but making any sound from either laptop immediately stops the play on the currently active laptop.

Comment: There was no way we could have known that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suddenly found out that my Bluetooth speaker was connected simultaneously to two laptops, and this BT device has no ability to play two streams of audio at once.

So the interruptions took place even without RDP, this problem has nothing to do with RDP.